# Is there anything people do today that would have been seen as a miracle by ancient standards?

Tags: global-christianity

Part of Christianity seems to be one's perpetual increase of love for other people. Jesus loved so perfectly that he was able to perform astonishing miracles, even by today's standards with all our technological advancements, and give us an example of what it looks like to do God's will.

Now that many billions are following his example, I'd like to think that we have gotten increasingly better at loving one another in the last 2000 years. So, is there anything commonplace we do today that would have been seen as miraculous or rare in ancient times?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: 'Many billions are following his example'. Rather I see the scripture fulfilled 'and all the world wondered after the beast' - and thus after Diabolos, the Serpent, the Tempter, the Drakon. that one Entity with various characteristics who leads the entire world astray, all nations and all ideologies . . . . .  save the little flock, who a re despised and persecuted and treated as outcasts by 'mainstream religion'. Thus are the last days, as we read. And in the last times there are miracles, done by the Enemy to mesmerise the nations. These are the 'miracles' to which, I think, you allude.

Comment: "*I'd like to think that we have gotten increasingly better at loving one another*" — many people like to think that. They are idealists, joyfully waiting for reality to catch up with their delusions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Jesus loved so perfectly that he was able to perform astonishing miracles

This is incorrect. Jesus either *is God* (according to Trinitarians; mainstream Christian belief), or was a prophet among prophets (Unitarian belief; considered heretical by most Christians)... which isn't *directly* relevant, as various prophets who all Christians believe were merely human have also done miracles.

*Nowhere*, however, are miracles attributes to one's ability to love. Miracles are gifts of God, and, particularly, are God's "signature", occurring in connection with prophets preaching God's Word as a means of authenticating that Word.

> Now that many billions are following his example [...]

Where are these "many billions" of which you speak? In the US, I would guess that only a modest fraction of the population remains truly Christian, and I very much doubt the percentage is higher in any place other than, perhaps, Africa. In all, I would be quite surprised if there are *one* billion genuine Christians around today.

To shamelessly steal [Nigel J](/users/38350)'s excellent comment:

> Rather I see the scripture fulfilled 'and all the world wondered after the beast' - and thus after Diabolos, the Serpent, the Tempter, the Drakon; that one Entity with various characteristics who leads the entire world astray, all nations and all ideologies . . . . . save the little flock, who are despised and persecuted and treated as outcasts by 'mainstream religion'. Thus are the last days, as we read. And in the last times there are miracles, done by the Enemy to mesmerise the nations.

Christian foundations and truths are being discarded for lies and immorality and social decline is on the rise. 'Miracles' are associated with false teaching or with non-Christian sources (fascination with 'aliens' and 'ghosts', neither of which are real) and are leading people *away* from Christ.

I've heard of one person who had a Vision, in which it was revealed that humanity is worse now than in the days of the Flood.

> So, is there anything commonplace we do today that would have been seen as miraculous or rare in ancient times?

It's possible, but if so, it would be as a result of our technology, little to do with Christianity. Therefore, further examination of this question is not on topic. (Carrying on a real-time conversation, with video, with someone halfway across the world or in orbit seems a likely candidate.)

That said... the idea that "ancient" people were less intelligent is very much rooted in the anti-Christian philosophy of Materialism. In reality, people of Biblical times accomplished feats that we can't replicate today. The improvement in technology is a result of population density, not any change in intelligence, and there are indications that, in fact, human intellectual ability has actually been *declining*. Thus, to assume that a human from a couple thousand years ago would be unable to understand modern technology may be an unwarranted leap.

Comment: Up-voted +1 Not just because you quoted me, but for a number of other reasons : ).